# Incomplete term slugs output from a foreach loop with get_the_terms

Tags: php, categories, terms

I'm using this PHP to get all the product category slugs on a single product page:

```
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
if(is_array($terms)){
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $product_cat_slug = $term->slug;
    $product_cat_slugs = ' product_cat-' . $product_cat_slug;
    echo $product_cat_slugs;
}
}
```

The line `echo $product_cat_slugs;` outputs `product_cat-category1 product_cat-category2`, which I will use for div classes.

The problem is that when I delete the `echo $product_cat_slugs;` from the function above and use `<?php echo $product_cat_slugs; ?>` elsewhere on the page, all I get for output is the last category slug `product_cat-category2`, and not both categories `product_cat-category1 product_cat-category2`.

What's wrong? It appears that `$product_cat_slugs` is overwritten when outside the foreach; how can I prevent that?

Answer (score -1):

You are overwriting `$product_cat_slugs` on every iteration of your loop - so when it's finished, that variable will be set to the last value.

Why not do all of your outputs inside that loop?

Or if for some reason you don't want to do that, make `$product_cat_slugs` an array instead of a variable:

```
$product_cat_slugs = [];
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $product_cat_slug = $term->slug;
    $product_cat_slugs[] = ' product_cat-' . $product_cat_slug;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that either gives me no output, or the error Array to string conversion with `echo $product_cat_slugs;` outside the loop.

Comment: You need to learn [how arrays work](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp) in PHP I think.

Comment: That's what we're here for, to learn :) Or at least I am.

Comment: Then you are in the wrong place to learn basic PHP, but I appreciate the downvote for trying to help you.

Comment: You're blaming *me* for your example not working?